# Generate script for backup. Invalid symbol in script

Tags: sql-server, backup, generate-scripts

```
INSERT [dbo].[ProcessingJob] ([DF], [ICNumber], [StationId], [UserId], 
[RecvDate], [StartDate], [CompleteDate], [BatchNumber], [GB1_D01], 
[GB1_D02], [GB1_D03], [GB1_D04], [GB1_D05], [GB1_D06], [GB1_D07], [GB1_D08], 
[GB1_D09], 3973964273964273964273964A7B9E4A84A65284A65284A65A84A65A84A65A84A65A8CA6638CA6638CAE638CA65A8CAE5A8CAE5A8CAE5A8CAE5A94AE5A94B65A94B65A94AE5A8CAE5A84A65284A6
```

When I generate script for a large database, many invalid character appeared in my script. Why ?

Comment: This is the output, but did you input to get this output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ya sure. I generate script from sql server management studio.

Comment: How exactly did you generate the script?

Comment: @Xedni right click database> Tasks> generate script